# Replace a bracket that matches a criteria

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

In the following string:

```
(my name is zeeze :) and I am very happy ;))
```

I need to replace all the `)` with `__BR__` that are part of the pattern satisfied by regex:

```
[8|:|;|\*]{1}[-c^;\*]?\)
```

Reference: [Regex playground](https://regex101.com/r/UMc5DX/2)

I cannot replace ending `)` because it is not part of the pattern.

What could be a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it in the callback method:

```js
var s = "(my name is zeeze :) and I am very happy ;))";
console.log(
  s.replace(/[8:;*][-c^;*]?\)/g, function($0) {
    return $0.replace(/\)/g, "__BR__")
  })
)
// => (my name is zeeze :__BR__ and I am very happy ;__BR__)
```

Note that `|` inside a character class `[8|:|;|\*]` is treated as a literal `|` pipe symbol, thus I think it is a human error. `{1}` is redundant as an atom is matched exactly once by default. There is no need to escape `*` char inside a character class, it is parsed as a literal asterisk symbol there.